Anylogic and NVidia Omniverse rendering
I am trying to connect my Anylogic model to the Omniverse, but once I add the path and file name in the "Render Model", the "Finish" button is not enabled so I can't render. Do you know how to fix this? I attach a picture of the screen where I can't continue.
I installed the Omniverse and the Omniverse USD Composer, I am unsure if other installations are required.


I figured out the error. It happens because the folder in the Omniverse path had spaces in the name. Make sure when you create the folder in Omniverse it has no spaces in the name, otherwise the model won't allow you to render 3D.

thx for sharing the answer as well, helps build a true KB :)
